# Error installing Application Request Routing

Tags: iis-7.5

I'm trying to install IIS Application Request Routing 2.5 - with WebPI 4.0 under Windows Server 2008R2.

Unfortunately no menu shows up in IIS Manager.

Instead I get the following error in Event Viewer:

> The Initialize method for module
>   "Microsoft.Web.Management.Arr.ArrModule,
>   Microsoft.Web.Management.Arr.Client, Version=7.2.4.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" of type "ApplicationRequestRouting"
>   threw an exception.
>
> Exception:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.Web.Management.WebFarmClient, Version=7.1.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. File name:
>   'Microsoft.Web.Management.WebFarmClient, Version=7.1.2.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Management.Arr.ArrModule.Initialize(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider, ModuleInfo moduleInfo)    at
>   Microsoft.Web.Management.Client.Connection.Initialize(WebManagementInfo
>   webManagementInfo)

Indeed the WebFarmClient DLL is in the GAC in Version 7.1.2.1.
(automatically resolved by WebPI)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK.. here's the solution.
Since another Version of the `WebFarmClient` DLL is in the GAC I had the idea to redirecting them:

Open `C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\config\administration.config`, which is the config file for **IIS MANAGER** (*not for IIS itself*).

Add this section into it (*after configsections*):

```xml
<!-- ... -->
</configSections>
<runtime>
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
         <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Web.Management.WebFarmClient"
                              publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"
                              culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="7.1.2.0"
                             newVersion="7.1.2.1"/>
         </dependentAssembly>
      </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Here we go!